# ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox does not show its items

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an **ASP.NET** application and I create dynamically several **combo boxes** with **AjaxControl Toolkit**. All **combo boxes** are filled up with data but some don't show the data.
Here is my code :

```
cbo = new AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox();

cbo.ID = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), "cbo{0}", RemoveSpecialCharacters(filter.Key)); // filter.key is the name of the combo
            cbo.AutoCompleteMode = AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBoxAutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            cbo.AutoPostBack = true;
            cbo.Visible = true;
            cbo.MaxLength = 500;

cbo.DataSource = GetFilterData2(requestId, filter.Key); // loads the data source with a list<string>
            cbo.DataBind();
            cbo.ItemInserted += this.CboItemInserted;
            this.cboFilters.Add(cbo);
            li.Controls.Add(cbo); // combo is added to the list item
```

when I inspect my HTML page with Chrome, I get for the combo which works:

```
<ul id="MainContent_cboScanner_cboScanner_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 1000; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; width: 213px; position: absolute; height: 464px; left: 334px; top: 242px; display: none;">
```

And for the one which doesn't display its items :

```
<ul id="MainContent_cboEnvironnement_cboEnvironnement_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
```

Why an AjaxControlToolkit combobox would not display its items despite having them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comboboxes after a bad textbox which had a space in the Id didn't show its items.
I added the Remove-special-characters method on all textboxes and the problem was solved.

Here is what I added:

```
txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"), "txt{0}", RemoveSpecialCharacters(filter.Key));
```

Here is my method:

```
private static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string mystring)
{
  return mystring.Trim().Replace(' ', '_').Replace("'", "_").Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty).Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
}
```